# How to reinstall the Windows Feedback app on Windows 10 Tech Preview?

Tags: windows-10-preview

I've uninstalled the Windows Feedback program from Windows 10. Is it possible to reinstall it? I can't find it on the Windows Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a [Microsoft Representative](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_apps-insider_feedback/windows-feedback-not-working-uninstall-app-but/7399e86d-b328-4eaa-b909-510b13712cff?tab=question&status=AllReplies&status=AllReplies#tabs) once removed the `Windows Feedback` application cannot be installed again and the only solution is to reinstall the `Windows 10 Technical Preview` from scratch.

> Feedback App once removed from your computer won't be reinstalled from
>   Windows Store. Here in this scenario, you will have to re-install
>   Windows 10 Technical Preview to get the Feedback App on your computer.

However, there's a simple workaround: just create a new user account. It will have all default apps as your original main account, including the Windows Feedback app.

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall Windows 10 default apps using PowerShell. Make sure you do that by running PowerShell as administrator. All you have to do is run this command:

```
Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

Windows 10 will installing all its default apps again. Note that this step might take more than just a few seconds to finish and you may see some alarming red messages inside the PowerShell window. Don't panic and let it do its job.

Here are more details including screen shots: [reinstall all the Windows 10 default apps with PowerShell](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-reinstall-all-windows-10-default-apps-powershell).

Comment: How? Could you [edit your answer](https://superuser.com/posts/1198442/edit) to include the relevant information from your link her please? Thanks! :)